# Are these modulus inequalities true?

Tags: inequality

I am working on some theorems on limits, for which I need to know whether the following inequalities hold. Honestly, I haven't put much effort into these, but if I can get some help, then I can save a lot of time.

Suppose there are six real numbers $l_1,l_2,a,b,c,d$ such that the following two inequalities hold:
$$|l_1-a|\le|l_1-b|\\
|l_2-c|\le|l_2-d|$$

Now, do the above inequalities imply the following inequalities?
$$|l_1+l_2-a-c|\le|l_1+l_2-b-d|\\
|l_1-l_2-a+c|\le|l_1-l_2-b+d|\\
|l_1l_2-ac|\le|l_1l_2-bd|\\
|\frac{l_1}{l_2}-\frac{a}{c}|\le|\frac{l_1}{l_2}-\frac{b}{d}|$$

For the last inequality, it is provided that $l_2,c,d\ne0$.

If not a proof, I will also be satisfied with a "yes" or "no" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. For example for the first one, $l_1=l_2 =0$, $a=c=1$, $b=2, d=-2$.